# Can Rmarkdown print a file's C++ code on GitHub?

Tags: c++, github, r-markdown, markdown

Rmarkdown can read a file and print it using

````
```{r}
fileName <- '../code/file.cpp'
readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
`` `
````

(without the space at the end)

Is is possible to use syntax coloring in it ?
The idea is that this would be converted to

````
```cpp
contents of the file
`` `
````

(without the space at the end)

before being converted to a HTML document.

Many thanks to anyone who will answer, and happy holidays !

Comment: With the current markdown, there is a solution . https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-code.html provides a solution

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do at this moment is copy the entire C++ code, paste it into the `Rcpp{}` chunk in the `pdf_document` output Rmarkdown file, this will render with your colored C++ code.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Daniel"
date: "3/31/2021"
output: pdf_document
---



```{Rcpp}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). Learn
// more about Rcpp at:
//
//   http://www.rcpp.org/
//   http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html
//   http://gallery.rcpp.org/
//

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}


// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
timesTwo(42)
*/
```
````

[image]

Comment: Not really. Put your c++ code in a file and find a way to make it appear in the pdf with syntax coloring. That's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: I updated my answer, it's better for like a single print out, rather than running reports due to it having a manual process.